# How to get Facebook photos me AND a specific friend are tagged in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't figure this... I have a Facebook app registered and can of course get all permissions needed, but would like to know... Is the following possible?

I have a friend called John. Now, I would like to get app photos I have access to where both ME and John are tagged in.

This could of course be in one of my photos, one of John's but also of course photos by other Facebook users like mutual friends.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

A shame this simple query doesn't work:

```
SELECT pid, object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=FRIEND_ID AND subject=me()
```

But here is a way:

```
SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo 
    WHERE pid IN(
          SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me()) 
      AND pid IN(
          SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=FRIEND_ID)
```